# Match two ids from the table to a different table PgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, inner-join

So, here I have a **exchange_rate** table with fromcurr_id and tocurr_id and the names of the currency according to the id's are in another table **currency**.

```
exchng_rate_id | fromcurr_id | tocurr_id | exchange_rate 
----------------+-------------+-----------+---------------
              1 |           1 |         2 |  5.0000000000
              2 |           1 |         3 |  3.0000000000
              3 |           1 |         4 |  6.0000000000
              4 |           1 |         5 |  2.0000000000
              5 |           2 |         3 |  5.0000000000
              6 |           2 |         4 |  7.0000000000
              7 |           2 |         5 |  3.0000000000
              8 |           3 |         4 |  1.0000000000
              9 |           3 |         5 |  4.0000000000
             10 |           4 |         5 |  2.0000000000
```

and here's the description for the currency table:

```
Column  |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |               Default                
---------+------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------
 id      | integer                |           | not null | nextval('currency_id_seq'::regclass)
 curr_id | integer                |           | not null | 
 name    | character varying(255) |           |          |
```

*I need to show what id belongs to what currency name.(ie., fromcurr_id = name and tocurr_id = name)*

This is what i tried...

Query1:
Tried inner join on the tables, but the result yields only the names of the fromcurr_id.

```
select name, fromcurr_id, tocurr_id, name, exchange_rate 
from exchange_rate 
  inner join currency on exchange_rate.fromcurr_id = currency.curr_id;
```

Result:

```
      name      | fromcurr_id | tocurr_id |      name      | exchange_rate 
----------------+-------------+-----------+----------------+---------------
 ************** |           1 |         2 | ************** |  5.0000000000
 ************** |           1 |         3 | ************** |  3.0000000000
 ************** |           1 |         4 | ************** |  6.0000000000
 ************** |           1 |         5 | ************** |  2.0000000000
 *************  |           2 |         3 | ************   |  5.0000000000
 ************   |           2 |         4 |**************  |  7.0000000000
 *************  |           2 |         5 | ************   |  3.0000000000
 ************** |           3 |         4 | ************** |  1.0000000000
 ************** |           3 |         5 | ************** |  4.0000000000
 ************** |           4 |         5 | ************** |  2.0000000000
(10 rows)
```

The name in the first case is same as the second case, and not according to the currency table. (Had to censor the data for confidentiality)

---

Query2:
Tried inner join with two conditions.

```
select name, fromcurr_id, tocurr_id, name, exchange_rate 
from exchange_rate 
  inner join currency on exchange_rate.fromcurr_id = currency.curr_id 
                     and exchange_rate.tocurr_id = currency.curr_id;
```

And this shows no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two `join`s, one for each currency:

```
select er.*, cfrom.*, cto.*
from exchange_rate er inner join
     currency cfrom
     on er.fromcurr_id = cfrom.curr_id join
     current cto
     on er.tocurr_id = eto.curr_id
```

Comment: Two joins worked. Thanks.
```
select e.fromcurr_id , c.name, e.tocurr_id, c1.name,e.exchange_rate from exchange_rate e inner join currency c 
on e.fromcurr_id = c.curr_id inner join currency c1 on e.tocurr_id = c1.curr_id;
```